# How to get live elements of a web page rendered by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a button to the page icloud.com/#reminders using a JavaScript bookmarklet. The source code on the page is mostly JavaScript and the actual elements take a while to appear, being brought in and rendered via AJAX. At this point the Firefox inspector shows a div.search-bar element, next to which the button should go. The first try at the bookmarklet, just to get my feet wet, is:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20s;s=document.getElementsByClassName("search-bar");alert(s.length);})();
```

The result is "0".

Edit:

I ran the bookmarklet after the element appears on the page.

How can I get at the rendered element?

Comment: What is `var%20s`?

Comment: Formatting error? AFAIK %20 is just an encoded space char

Comment: Other than that, not easy to do what you want. One workaround may be to execute your bookmarklet with a timeout so you can be sure the page is loaded. Of course thats not stable. Another solution would be to constantly poll for this element using `setInterval` and stop either after a certain time, or at the moment you have found the element you are looking for. Not nice, but should work.

Comment: Yes, the %20 is an encoded space, no spaces/returns allowed in the javascript:... string.

Comment: I should have explained that I wait for the elements to appear before clicking the bookmarklet. So the div should be there - but it isn't.